# unity native plugin-Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have created a android native library for unity which is a fragment that shows a screen on the unity game screen.

everything works fine, but now i'm trying to add custom font to my android library layout. but by adding any new fonts to font folder under 'res' folder in android library and exporting to arr file, i get this error in unity when trying to Build and Run:

[image]

Error text:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.  C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.4.jar"
>   org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m"
>   "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':unity-android-resources:packageReleaseResources'.
>
>   > C:\Users\Shetab\Documents\UnityPlugin\Temp\gradleOut\unity-android-resources\res\font\bahush.TTF:1:1:
>   >     Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s ] stdout[ NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
>   If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK
>   directory.  It is currently set to C:\sdk\ndk-bundle. If you are not
>   using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or
>   local.properties to remove this warning.
>
> Observed package id 'build-tools;29.0.0-rc2' in inconsistent location
>   'C:\sdk\29.0.0-rc2' (Expected 'C:\sdk\build-tools\29.0.0-rc2')
>   Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location
>   'C:\sdk\toolsXXXX' (Expected 'C:\sdk\tools') Already observed package
>   id 'tools' in 'C:\sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\sdk\toolsXXXX'
>   NDK is missing a "platforms" directory. If you are using NDK, verify
>   the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to
>   C:\sdk\ndk-bundle. If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable
>   from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.
>
> The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is
>   scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the
>   CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead. The
>   setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to
>   be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the
>   setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead. The
>   getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be
>   removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method
>   instead. The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been
>   deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
>   the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead. :preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE :checkReleaseManifest
>   :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :prepareUnitylibraryDebugLibrary
>   :unity-android-resources:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :unity-android-resources:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :unity-android-resources:checkReleaseManifest
>   :unity-android-resources:prepareReleaseDependencies
>   :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseAidl
>   :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
>   :unity-android-resources:compileLint
>   :unity-android-resources:copyReleaseLint NO-SOURCE
>   :unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseShaders
>   :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseShaders
>   :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseAssets
>   :unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseAssets
>   :unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
>   :unity-android-resources:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseRenderscript
>   :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResValues
>   :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResources
>   :unity-android-resources:packageReleaseResources
>   C:\Users\Shetab\Documents\UnityPlugin\Temp\gradleOut\unity-android-resources\res\font\bahush.TTF:1:1:
>   Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   :unity-android-resources:packageReleaseResources FAILED 13 actionable
>   tasks: 12 executed, 1 up-to-date ] exit code: 1
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun
>   (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava
>   (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1
>   progress, System.String error) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
>   (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1
>   progress) Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir,
>   System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to get a custom font from `res/font` folder in this case.
for this, you have to save font in android `assets` folder and load it programmatically in your code:

```
   TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

   Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf");

   tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```